# Different position of my array

Tags: php, json

Im currently in the making of a website, to show of LoL Stats, but here comes the tricky one ^^.

When I try to get the stats, not all players have played all the different game modes, so lets say, that

Player 1, has played only one game mode, so the array would look like this:

```
[0] => Array
           (
                [playerStatSummaryType] => Unranked
                [wins] => 141
                [losses] => 0
                [modifyDate] => 1389338360000
                [aggregatedStats] => Array
                    (
                        [totalChampionKills] => 1114
                        [totalMinionKills] => 36216
                        [totalTurretsKilled] => 287
                        [totalNeutralMinionsKilled] => 2265
                        [totalAssists] => 1923
                    )

            )
```

Then player 2, have played 3 game modes, then it would like look this.

```
[0] => Array
            (
                [playerStatSummaryType] => AramUnranked5x5
                [wins] => 2
                [losses] => 0
                [modifyDate] => 1389254885000
                [aggregatedStats] => Array
                    (
                        [totalChampionKills] => 38
                        [totalTurretsKilled] => 2
                        [totalAssists] => 77
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [playerStatSummaryType] => OdinUnranked
                [wins] => 0
                [losses] => 0
                [modifyDate] => 1376980500000
                [aggregatedStats] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [playerStatSummaryType] => OneForAll5x5
                [wins] => 0
                [losses] => 0
                [modifyDate] => 1388558434000
                [aggregatedStats] => Array
                    (
                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [playerStatSummaryType] => Unranked
                [wins] => 141
                [losses] => 0
                [modifyDate] => 1389338360000
                [aggregatedStats] => Array
                    (
                        [totalChampionKills] => 1114
                        [totalMinionKills] => 36216
                        [totalTurretsKilled] => 287
                        [totalNeutralMinionsKilled] => 2265
                        [totalAssists] => 1923
                    )

            )
```

That thing I want to do here, is get the [playerStatSummaryType] => Unranked, but how am i able to do this, when in the first example it located at[0], in the second in [3] and so on.

Cause if I took the [0] everytime, it would come with wrong stats

Hope someone can help me out :)

Comment: Do you want to filer all array elements that has `playerStatSummaryType == "Unranked"`? Then you can try http://se2.php.net/array_filter

Comment: Will try that later, will respond with results

Comment: Cant really get it to working ,getting wrong syntax error, when im trying to use == "Unranked". Will add my code soon

Answer (score 1):

you mean it will always be on the last index?

Comment: Use comments to comment and ask clarifying questions!

Comment: can't add comments.. my reputation score is < 50

Comment: Really, didn't know that. Well you're not that far away :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a foreach loop, or maybe [array_map()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with a recursive function...
You might want to consider using a database (SQL or object-based). Multidimentional arrays are not great for searching and stuff like that.

Comment: How can i use a database with this?

Comment: You just save your data in a database (MySQL, CouchDB, etc.) instead of saving it in arrays... OK it's more complicated, especially if you don't have experience with databases, but it's much more convenient for searching your data afterwards if you have complicated data. It might be too much for this case, though, especially if you don't need to persist your data.